# ValueError: substring not found in midi

Tags: python, arduino, midi

Let me first start this off by stating that I am a complete beginner to coding and my attempts to fix this have been limited. I am trying to follow this [Arduino controlled piano robot](https://www.hackster.io/MoKo/arduino-controlled-piano-robot-pibot-641a06). It takes a textified midi file and uses python to translate it into 8-bit. The code is attached near the bottom of the link, I had some formatting issues when placing it here.

[This link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13hApM7dlHDoxOguDv29ThJgVEvr4hHyg/view?usp=sharing) to the textified midi file used. before running the code I changed the input_file = open to text file path like so,

```
input_file = open("C:\\Users\\nby20\\Downloads\\megalovania.txt")
```

After running the code I get a text output file as expected however it is blank and I get a few errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation.py", line 184, in <module>
   main()
File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation.py", line 23, in main
   result[-1] = str(temp_time) + "," + set_bit_prev(on_off_finder(a), note_finder(a), -1)
File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation.py", line 178, in on_off_finder
   end = in_string.index("ch=") - 1

ValueError: substring not found
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `Traceback` is like debugging information you can use to trace which functions were called when the error was thrown. It seems the error occurred when it was executing this bit of conditional logic, lines 22-23, of the `main` function:

```
elif time_finder_comm(result[-1]) == temp_time:
    result[-1] = str(temp_time) + "," + set_bit_prev(on_off_finder(a), note_finder(a), -1)
```

which called the `on_off_finder` function which just tries to figure out if the line says 'On' or 'Off'.

It seems the file reader only expects lines like this:

```
55248 Off ch=10 n=40 v=64
```

However, in the file you uploaded, there also lines like this:

```
55248 Meta TrkEnd
TrkEnd
```

The `index` function throws `ValueError: substring not found` if the substring passed in does not exist in the string, which in this case (line 178 below) is the string `"ch"`:

```
end = in_string.index("ch=") - 1
```

Try removing those kind of lines and re-run the script? Find all lines with "Trk" and and remove them, or make 3 separate files because there seem to be 3 blocks of lines in 'megalovania.txt' that will trip up the script:

```
(starting at line 2469):
55248 Meta TrkEnd
TrkEnd
MTrk

...
(starting at line 4071):
58368 Meta TrkEnd
TrkEnd
MTrk

...
(starting at line 6431):
55296 Meta TrkEnd
TrkEnd
```

Comment: tried that and i got a similar error message Traceback (most recent call last):
 'File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation (1).py", line 184, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation (1).py", line 12, in main
    temp_time = time_finder(a)
  File "C:\Users\nby20\Downloads\python_code_for_translation (1).py", line 161, in time_finder
    time_end = in_string.index(" ")
ValueError: substring not found'

Comment: Seems to be failing on an empty line now (it says that a space character wasn't found). Since like every type of line has a space, I have to assume it crashed on the last line (which was an empty line). Honestly this script you're using is not very clean/forgiving and I'm just guessing here. If you want others to be able to troubleshoot this with you, you should probably have some shared folder (with a constant public link) that has the script you're running, the file you're running it with, and a `error.txt` file that has the current state of the error.